# How can you move a file as a background job and delete all other files and the directory before waiting for the job to finish?

Tags: rm, mv, jobs

I downloaded a directory of files, `directory.1`

containing the files

```
file.1
file.2
file.3
```

I move `file.2` by

```
mv file.2 ../another.directory &
```

My problem is I want to get rid of `directory.1` and the contents but I have to wait for my job to finish.  Is there a way around this?  Or a quick way to do a..

```
rm -r directory.1
```

triggered when my `mv` job is finished?

edit:  to be clear...  the file I'm moving is ~1GB to another device.  So can take a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just aggregate the two commands with `&&`:

```
cd ..
mv directory.1/file.2 another.directory && rm -r directory.1 &
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it within the `directory.1`?  'Cause sometimes I don't know what the file is called.

Comment: Well, it seems like `rm` doesn't like deleting `.` and `..`. I recommend using `"$OLDPWD"` in the place of `directorry.1` where you don't know its name.